# On a criterion for unimodular matrix

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

A matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}w &x \\\ y &z\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb Z^{2\times 2}$$ is unimodular if $$|wz-xy|=1$$ holds.

> Is there a parametrization of such matrices with $2wy>(wz+xy)$ and $2xz>(wz+xy)$ with $wz-xy=1$?

Comment: Can you indicate your motivation for the question?

Comment: I think there is none. Seems too strong of a constraint.

Comment: Then why are you interested in parametrizing the matrices  subject to those constraints: for no actual reason?

Comment: I think there is no unimodular matrix with such tight constraints as $(wz+xy)<2wy,2xz$. Whatever I think of gets a best of $2xz<wz+xy<2wy,(2+\epsilon)xz$.

Comment: Any unimodular matrix with positive first column and negative second column satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @GHfromMO I was looking at only non-negative $w,x,y,z$.

Comment: For nonnegative $w,x,y,z$ there is no matrix satisfying the two inequalities. See my response below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP clarified in a comment that the variables $w,x,y,z$ were meant to be nonnegative. Under this restriction, the pair of inequalities
$$2wy>wz+xy\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2xz>wz+xy$$
has no solution. Indeed, these inequalities feature nonnegative numbers on both sides, hence multiplying them yields
$$4wxyz>(wz+xy)^2.$$
Rearranging, we get
$$0>(wz-xy)^2,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: So, in particular, the solutions are very easy to parameterise. 

Comment: Need coffee......